# how to get data from MySQL database in a way faster than querying?

Tags: mysql, database

I am querying a huge amount of data from the MySQL database whenever a user requests data. and I want to provide this data everytime a new user request for it. but  I don't want to waste time by querying the database every single time a user requests it. is there a way where I can store that huge data and provide it more easily for the next user without the need to query again and again?

Comment: Does the queries which are executed by different users are absolutely the same?

Comment: You can use cache, there are lot of cache technologies, it depends of yours.

Comment: Many possible answers; please elaborate on your case.  Caching, summarizing, avoiding, adding index, reformulating, etc.

Comment: A simple query takes so few milliseconds that the effort is not a problem.  For a slow query, show us the `SELECT`, `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.